# Sed - How to put brackets around the second word

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following sed command which puts brackets around the first word - (hello) - i thought if I wanted to change this to put the brackets around the second word all I had to do was change (\1) to (\2) as I thought this would pick up the second word but it does not work - what is the correct way to reference rthe second word then ?

```
 echo "hello world" | sed -re 's/(^\w*)/(\1)/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The \2 does not refer to the second word, but to the second bracketed expression. Therefore, bracketing both words should work:

```
echo hello world | sed -r 's/(\w+) (\w+)/\1 (\2)/'
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for this:

```
echo "hello world" | sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\2/'
```

world

```
echo "hello world" | sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1/'
```

hello

Swap the words:

```
echo "hello world" | sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\2 \1/'
```

world hello

...and insert brackets:

```
echo "hello world" | sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1 [\2]/'
```

hello [world]

How it works:
  .* .*   matches the two words "hello world"

Next, indicate the areas of interest by surrounding those by backslashed parentheses.

A good tutorial here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-sed2/index.html

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
echo "hello world" | sed -re 's/\w+/(&)/g'
```

or

```
echo "hello world" | sed -re 's/(^\w*)(\s*)(\w*)/(\1)\2(\3)/'
```

To bracket just the 2nd word:

```
echo "hello world" | sed -re 's/\w*/(&)/2'
```

To bracket the 2nd word onwards:

```
echo "hello brave new world" | sed -re 's/\w*/(&)/2g'
```